# I'm looking to replace point instance in blender 3.3.0

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm watching this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FVYTC90Aok) timer 23:54, he's using instance point in the geometry nodes editor, and i don't know how to do that on blender 3.3.0, i saw there was instance to/on points but i don't achieve what I want. Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be something like this in *Geometry Nodes Fields*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much !!